# SDE FeatureClass Granting and Revoking Privilege with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, oracle-dbms

**How can I with ArcObjects GRANT or REVOKE Privileges like SELECT, UPDATE on SDE FeatureClasses to/from Roles?**

The equivalent in normal *Oracle* would be something like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA.TABLE TO SOME_ROLE;
REVOKE SELECT ON SCHEMA.TABLE FROM SOME_ROLE;
```

I can't seem to find the interface to perform this task, and it may not exists?

My dream would be to have an Interface like this:

```
public interface IPrivilegeManager
{
    void Grant(string privilegeName, string schemaOwnerName, string featureClassName, string roleName);
    void Revoke(string privilegeName, string schemaOwnerName, string featureClassName, string roleName);
}
```

**Related Q:** [For a SDE FeatureClasses list all Roles that have been Granted any Privileges on it, and which Privileges each Role have on it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65280/for-a-sde-featureclasses-list-all-roles-that-have-been-granted-any-privileges-on)

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  As noted in your "question", you are actually asking two questions so I would recommend that you split them so that we can have a clean Q&A for each issue.

Comment: thank you @PolyGeo for the comment and welcome. :) The Questions are very closely related, but i partially agree with you. I'm not sure what the Header should be for the two questions.

Comment: I think exactly what you have next to Q1 and Q2 would be fine.

Comment: I for one believe that splitting the questions actually brings more confusion rather than adds any real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the name object for the given feature class and cast it to [ISQLPrivilege](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000084t000000), which allows you to enumerate, grant and revoke permissions.

E.g.:

```
var name = ((IDataset) featureClass).FullName;
var sqlPrivilege = name as ISQLPrivilege;
if (sqlPrivilege != null)
{
    sqlPrivilege.Grant("USER_OR_ROLE_NAME", (int) esriSQLPrivilege.esriSelectPrivilege, false);
}
```

Comment: Really? :D ill get right on testing this! If this works Ill burst into joy!

Comment: What type is featureClass in your example, currently i have a list of all the featureClasses in type IFeatureClassName and im unable to cast to IDataset, but i can cast to IDatasetName

Comment: In my snippet, it is of type IFeatureClass. So if you have a IFeatureClassName, you have the name the object already, so you can cast it directly to ISQLPrivilege.

Comment: Also, be sure to read the docs for ISQLPrivilege, especially the part about feature classes nested in a feature dataset. Privileges for those cannot be managed separately, but it needs to be done on the whole feature dataset.

Comment: I splitted the questions since your answer only answered the second question and not the first.

Comment: Which question is it? Does ISQLPrivilege.SQLPrivileges not satisfy your requirement of examining existing privileges? If not, then you're out of luck as far as ArcObjects go.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65280/for-a-sde-featureclasses-list-all-roles-that-have-been-granted-any-privileges-on is the question, The privileges i get back with ISQLPrivilege.esriSQLPrivileges is only the privileges the current loged in user has on the object. I need from a Role or FeatureClass perspective to see which FeatureClass/Role it is associated with and with what privileges.