# For a SDE FeatureClasses list all Roles that have been Granted any Privileges on it, and which Privileges each Role have on it

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, oracle-dbms

I have searched through the `ArcObjects 10 SDK` [API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_namespaces/000800000002000000/) and googled, but havnt been able to find what I am looking for, so thats the reason for me posting this question.

**Q: How can I for a SDE FeatureClasses list all Roles that have been Granted any Privileges on it, and which Privileges each Role have on it?**

The equivalent in normal *Oracle* would be something like this:

```
SELECT dtp.PRIVILEGE,
       dtp.grantable ADMIN,
       dtp.grantee,
       dtp.grantor,
       dbo.owner,
       dbo.object_type,
       dbo.object_name,
       dbo.status,
       '' column_name
  FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS dtp, ALL_OBJECTS dbo
 WHERE dtp.TABLE_SCHEMA = dbo.owner AND dtp.table_name = dbo.object_name
       AND dbo.object_type IN ( 'TABLE', 'VIEW' )
UNION
SELECT dcp.PRIVILEGE,
       dcp.grantable ADMIN,
       dcp.grantee,
       dcp.grantor,
       dbo.owner,
       dbo.object_type,
       dbo.object_name,
       dbo.status,
       dcp.column_name
  FROM ALL_COL_PRIVS dcp, ALL_OBJECTS dbo
 WHERE dcp.TABLE_SCHEMA = dbo.owner AND dcp.table_name = dbo.object_name
       AND dbo.object_type IN ( 'TABLE', 'VIEW' )
```

The query would list out all object of the types in the list provided (in the example I have listed `TABLE` and `VIEW`) which privileges have been granted on them like `SELECT`, `UPDATE` etc... and to which Roles.

**Related Q:** [SDE FeatureClass Granting and Revoking Privilege with ArcObjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65243/sde-featureclass-granting-and-revoking-privilege-with-arcobjects)

Comment: Please edit your post to link to your other related question.

Comment: @PetrKrebs done! :) I also added this question as a related question to this one on the other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to query the underlying `DBMS, Geodatabase`, to get the information I needed.
Here is the query I came up with for `SDE 10+`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (SELECT GDBI.PHYSICALNAME NAME, GDBIT.NAME TYPE_NAME
            FROM SDE.GDB_ITEMS GDBI, SDE.GDB_ITEMTYPES GDBIT
           WHERE GDBI.TYPE = GDBIT.UUID) GDBITJ,
         (SELECT A.OWNER,
                 A.GRANTABLE ADMIN,
                 A.GRANTEE,
                 A.GRANTOR,
                 A.PRIVILEGE,
                 A.TABLE_NAME
            FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS A
           WHERE     A.PRIVILEGE IN ('SELECT', 'UPDATE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE')
                 AND A.OWNER NOT IN ('SYS', 'SDE', 'SYSTEM')) AR
   WHERE        TYPE_NAME = 'Feature Class'
            AND UPPER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (NAME,
                                      '.[^.]+.',
                                      1,
                                      2)) = UPPER (TABLE_NAME)
         OR UPPER (NAME) = UPPER (TABLE_NAME)
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

If somebody have tips and tricks or improvements to this query please let me know.
As Travis stated in his answer, I will have to make such a query for all database types,
also, the `SDE Datamodel` was **changed** from `SDE 9.3.1` to `SDE 10+` so that also needs to be taken into account.

Also there is no guarantee that the `SDE Schema` you want to query will be named `SDE` in `SDE 10+`, as a database can hold **multiple** `SDE Schemas`. However in the table `SDE.Instances` all schemas will be listed.

**EDIT1:**

The comments on the answer I think are rather useful, so I added them to the answer.
Here is how to retrieve the schema name for an `IWorkspace` instance:

```
public string GetSchema()
{
    var versionWorkspace = _workspace as IVersionedWorkspace;
        if (versionWorkspace == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException("Failed to cast IWorkspace to IVersionedWorkspace");
    try
    {
        var versionName = versionWorkspace.DefaultVersion.VersionName;
        var schema = versionName.Split('.')[0];
        return schema;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to split versionName to get schemaName for the current SDE Workspace", ex);
    }
}
```

With the use of the `GetSchema()` method we can now modify the Query in the top to use the schema we get back as an input parameter, how you modify the query string is up to you, you only need to switch out the `SDE.*` schema name with the one retrieved with `GetSchema()` e.g: `OTHER_SDE_SCHEMA.*`

Comment: You could use the SDE.Layers table rather than the GDB_ tables.  There the table names are separated into user and table name columns, and match whatever the database name case is (upper case for Oracle, lower case for postgres).  Also, multiple geodatabases were introduced at 9.2 (maybe 9.3) for Oracle only.  I have found that the easiest way to tell what schema you want to check, is to find out the owner of the default version.

Comment: I know I read somewhere in the documentation that in the case of multiple geodatabases, the default schema will always be named SDE. So in order to get all the other instances you would look for them in the `SDE.INSTANCES` table as I stated in my answer. correct me if I'm wrong. I am very new to the SDE Database Model so I may be wrong, but how would I know which of the rows in `SDE.LAYERS` are Feature Classes? The reason for picking `GDB_ITEMS` was that I could join it with `GDB_ITEMTYPES` to get the Type.

Comment: You are right, but to tell what schema geodatabase you are connected to, you can check the owner of the default version.  Ie, if you are connected to the travis schema geodatabase, the default version would be travis.Default.  SDE layers are feature classes, tables and feature classes are listed in the sde.table_registry.  The only issue using the sde.layer or sde.table_registry tables as a source of information may be that geodatabase tables are listed there too.  For example, topologies have Dirty_Area tables.  These would be listed in the sde.layers table, but not in the geodatabase.

Comment: @travis how do I query for schema of the connected workspace? I tried to cast `IWorkspace` to `IFeatureWorkspace`, called `CreateQueryDef()` and then Queried for table `"Version"`, but as I connect to the workspace with `"OSA" (Operating System Authentication)` it queried with my schema...

Comment: Just use the IVersionedWorkspace interface to get the name of the default version.  It should be something like ___((IVersionedWorkspace)workspace).DefaultVersion.VersionName___.  Not all workspaces are Versioned Workspaces, so you may want to be careful with that cast.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people doing this using a direct connection via direct Oracle connection.

However, take a look at the ISQLPrivilege interface:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000084t000000

Answer (score 0):

At 10.1 there is a new privileges dialog that displays this information.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is an API to go along with it.  There is this [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/03/simplified-management-of-user-privileges-10-1/) on the new functionality.

I guess you could also just run a query layer to get the information directly.  The downside is that you will have to have a different query for every DBMS.